# Website fetch, using NSURLSession and changing INPUT Field value on this site

Tags: ios, xcode, html, onchange, nsurlsession

I wanna fetch the content of a website. But to get the correct content, it is necessary to change a Input Html sroll field on the side?

Many idea how to manage with xcode?

Thanks a lot!!

Lars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to retrieve the HTML that you get after filling in a HTML form, you have to identify precisely what the series of requests looks like to fetch the data. And be careful because it's often not as simple as just looking at the request that the HTML in question generates: unfortunately, it is sometimes a complex series of requests (e.g. retrieving the original HTML is often seamlessly retrieving some critical hidden form fields and/or cookies).

Bottom line, to reverse engineer the required HTTP requests, you often have to pour through HTML code and/or watch the requests with something like [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com). It often takes quite a bit of time to do this with complicated sites.

Before you invest a lot of time here, though, you should first see if the web site provider's Terms of Service permit such usage. They often strictly prohibit this sort of practice. It's much better to contact the web site provider and see if they provide a web service to retrieve the data. That's far easier and will result in a far more robust interface for your app.

But if you're forced programmatically parsing HTML, I'd refer you to [How to Parse HTML on iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios) on Ray Wenderlich's site.